# What is equal method to getStructuringElement() in javacv?

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I'm developing project which use image processing technique. In that I'm using javacv package which act as interface to call opencv methods. So there are lot of tutorials and materials for the opencv but there are less number of materials are available for the javacv. So I have found a method call getStructuringElement().

Please can some one explain the similar method in javacv and the purpose of this method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `cvCreateStructuringElementEx`.

Here's simple [example](http://javacv-examples.googlecode.com/svn-history/r24/trunk/OpenCV2_Cookbook/src/main/scala/opencv2_cookbook/chapter05/Ex1ErodingAndDilating.scala) of using it.